# Ошибка при открытии сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

при открытии сайта инспектор выдает такую ошибку 
index.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded

в интернете ответа так и не нашел. помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

Comment: пишите видать что-то большое в хранилище локальное, или сессионное ?

Comment: что простите? не совсем понял суть вопроса. можно попроще пожалуйста

Comment: где-то на вашей странице есть код вида `sessionStorage.setItem('some_key', something)`, и вот размер этого `something` больше, чем максимальный размер элемента который можно так использовать.

Comment: а где его найти, как изменить, и что собственно изменять чтобы избавиться от этой ошибки?

Comment: судя по вашим вопросам, очевидно, поручить эту задачу специалисту, который мало-мальски разбирается в вопросе.

Comment: @RamCe попробуйте открыть эту страницу в другом браузере. Вероятно это какие-то [расширения вызывают ошибку](https://github.com/petko10/real-time-tab-sync/issues/4), если они конечно у вас есть.

Comment: пробовал. обычно открываю все в Яндекс браузере. также открывал в хроме, тоже самое.